# $facebook->getUser(); still returns 0

Tags: php, facebook

I have a development site and a production site running on a shared server. I use fb_loginUrl with the following code, which works.

I'm moving the production site to a new domain, also on the shared server. I copied the entire code including the PHP SDK. I've used the new domain's appID and secret. On the new domain, fb_loginUrl shows the login dialog if needed, correctly calls FB, and receives a GET call back. But user is always 0, even if there is a user logged in on the machine. There is not a CSRF error. If I keep going round the endless loop, it does throw a CSRF error the second time, and every second time after that.

The problem should be somewhere in the settings for the new app, but they're the same as the old ones with names and addresses updated, and I've tried the changes I can think of including a trailing slash on the return url. I'm starting to wonder if FB applies some different invisible defaults to newly registered apps (not completely paranoid - default settings on the web dashboard are different, such as the value of "deprecate offline_access" - but I've brought everything into line with my old setup).

Why might this run differently in different domains?

```
require_once '../facebook/facebook.php';
if(!isset($facebook)) $facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $facebook_appid,
  'secret' => $fb_secret,
  'scope' => 'email'
));

$fb_user = $facebook->getUser();
echo ' USER: ' . $fb_user;

if ($fb_user) {
  try {
    $fb_user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
  }
}
```

Comment: after u moved site do u access new site with same url as before?

Comment: Nope, different url, and different FB app id. And you gave me an idea. I tried using the old FB app on the new domain, and it works! So that gives me a workaround. But I still don't know why this would happen, because the old app now has exactly the same settings as the new one.

Comment: do have this issue in every browser?

Answer (score 0):

I think getUser just pulls data from cookie, so try adding

'cookie' => true,
to new Facebook call, e.g.

```
 new Facebook(array(
   'appId'  => $facebook_appid,
   'secret' => $fb_secret,
   'scope' => 'email',
   'cookie' => true,
```

If you test app outside of facebook chrome by going directly to iframe, make sure url matches to what you put in canvas url in app settings, e.g. if there is a www in front or not.

Comment: Well, the code is working now, with a different FB appID. So the problem is somewhere around the particular app. Facebook certainly stores a pile of info in a cookie, but when I tried adding that line a few days ago it didn't make a difference, and I think I heard it isn't needed for the current SDK.